# GitHub Pages build failure due to “nil was passed to a date-related filter that expects valid dates in 'index.html' or one of its layouts

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

On my Jekyll page I get this error once I commit to GitHub:

```
The page build failed with the following error:
```

> ```
> The value 'nil' was passed to a date-related filter that expects valid dates in index.html or one of its layouts.
> ```

Any idea how to fix it? I went through all posts and checked the Front Matter but can't find anything wrong...

my repo is on https://github.com/el3ctron/el3ctron.github.io/ displaying http://el3ctron.github.io page.

Answer (score 1):

If all your dates are valid, I'd say it's this file: https://github.com/el3ctron/el3ctron.github.io/blob/master/_posts/%232016-10-19-Caldas.markdown%23

It doesn't fit the required format for filenames within the _posts folder as it starts with a #. This will make the date `nil` as the format is invalid, then eventually throw that error when it's used in `{{ post.date | date: "%Y" }}`.

Either rename it or remove it.

You might also be having issues with this symlink file: https://github.com/el3ctron/el3ctron.github.io/blob/master/_posts/.%232016-10-19-Caldas.markdown, which I'd also try to remove.

Comment: already deleted the files and exactly the same problem continues